# How to check if a user has granted a certain permission Facebook iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

In my iOS app, I just want to check if the user has granted the Facebook publish_stream permission.

I'm not sure how to handle the response to the call

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];
```

in my FBRequest delegate method. I've tried:

```
if (request == self.permissionRequest) {
        NSString *key = [result objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
        DLog(@"Key: %@", key);
    }
```

But I get null.

And if I try

```
    id *key = [result objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
int keyInt = [key integerValue];
DLog(@"Key: %i", keyInt);
```

I always get 0. Even when I know the permission is active...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an FBRequest with the open graph API with "me/permissions".
It will return you a response with a dictionary where the key are the permissions. a value will be associated (1 = YES, 0 = NO)

Comment: And this really is the quickest way? Because I want to do this test at the same time as checking if the current session is valid and it will take a few seconds... I suppose I could try to do the test before hand...

Comment: I think this is the best way... but there is no SDK method to do so, if that's your question...

Comment: I've tried id key = [result objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
        DLog(@"Key: %@", key); but 'key' is null?

Comment: And casting it as an int always returns 0... Am I handling it wrong?

Comment: print all keys if you have a doubt, but in general FBRequest return a dictionary like { data = {//some data} }

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532962/objectforkey-always-returning-null-or-0-when-i-know-the-value-to-be-1

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working sample I did for create_events.  Sure it could be used for others:

```
FBRequest *eventPostOK = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:Nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[eventPostOK startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
NSDictionary* result,
NSError *error) {
      BOOL canDoIt = FALSE;
      if (!error)
      {
         FBGraphObject *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         for(NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *aKey in data) {
             canDoIt = [[aKey objectForKey:@"create_event"] boolValue];
             }
      }
      else
         NSLog(@"%@", error);

      NSLog(@"%@", canDoIt ? @"I can create Events" : @"I can't create Events");
      }];
```