# ObjectForKey always returning null or 0 when I know the value to be 1

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, nsdictionary

I've made a call to retrieve a user's active permissions using

```
self.permissionRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];
```

(I set the FBRequest object so I can identify it in the delegate method)

In the delegate I call:

```
        if (request == self.permissionRequest) {
        DLog(@"Result: %@", result);

    }
```

And I get a nice print out of active permissions:

> Result: {
>       data =     (
>                   {
>               bookmarked = 1;
>               "create_note" = 1;
>               email = 1;
>               installed = 1;
>               "photo_upload" = 1;
>               "publish_stream" = 1;
>               "share_item" = 1;
>               "status_update" = 1;
>               "video_upload" = 1;
>           }
>       );
>   }

All well so far.

BUT I just want to determine if the "publish_stream" is on or off.

If I call

```
id *key = [result objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
int keyInt = [key integerValue];
DLog(@"Key: %i", keyInt);
```

I always get 0.

If I call

```
NSString *key = [result objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
    DLog(@"Key: %@", key);
```

I get 'null'.

What am I doing wrong?? Why can't I get the value of the publish_stream key? I've also tried using valueForKey: with the same results.

There must be a remarkably simple solution?

Comment: Key should be `id`, not `id*`, in the fourth code block. Not the problem, but a problem.

Comment: Hello, I want to implement same kind of functionality using social framework. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your result dictionary has just one key, `data`, whose value is another dictionary, and everything else is inside that.

Try

```
[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"publish_stream"];
```

You also have another error: you wrote

```
id *key
```

An `id` is already a pointer. You shouldn't put a `*` after it unless you want a double pointer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! The only thing worth noting is that it has to be valueForKey:@"publish_stream" otherwise it kicks up a fuss.